# Error when creating a new keystore in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, keystore

I am trying to create a new keystore to sign my apks with in eclipse using the android tools. I work through the wizard and at the end i get this error :

keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException (Access is denied)

I can't seem to figure out why i keep getting this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is "access is denied". Mostly likely you don't have permissions to create the keystore in the folder that you specified. Try creating it in your user directory. If I had to guess I would say you're probably using Windows and saving to the `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)` folder which you can't write to without elevated privileges.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I ended up just running eclipse as an admin and that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Becuase the keystore creation file is not in the valid location.
Please check the location before creating the file and give full rights to that folder.
if again if you are getting the same error then copy required library files in the keystore folder. it will work sure. all the best.

Regards
Venkatesh KR